# (node:8828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

Tags: cordova, phonegap

```
C:\Users\pc\Converter>cordova run android --emulator
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk-10.0.1
(node:8828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Requirements check 
failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
at C:\Users\pc\Converter\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:370:19
at _fulfilled 
(C:\Users\pc\Converter\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done 
(C:\Users\pc\Converter\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch 
(C:\Users\pc\Converter\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
at 
C:\Users\pc\Converter\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
at runSingle 
(C:\Users\pc\Converter\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
at flush 
(C:\Users\pc\Converter\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:8828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without 
a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with 
.catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8828) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This Error was shown when I run 'Cordova run android' command in cmd. But I have installed Java JDK 1.8.